# Join tables based on first table column value (Lambda query)

Tags: c#, linq, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 tables :

- Delivery tbl
- InternalDriver tbl
- ExternalDriver tbl

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, how can I get a collection from `Delivery` table that will fetch `DriverNames` from other tables performing only one lambda query?

Things to be considered:

- When `DriverType` is `Internal`, then it should get `DriverNames` from the `InternalDriver` table
- When `DriverType` is `External`, then it should get `DriverNames` from the `ExternalDriver` table

Comment: Did you mean LINQ query instead of Lambda query?

Comment: @Oleksandr Pshenychnyy , I am looking for a method syntax , NOT query syntax

Comment: Mohammad, is there a reason why you have two tables for drivers, since if you didn't it would significantly simplify your join?

Comment: @john I am working on a existing project, that's how the tables are designed before. Here, i am only trying to resolve the issue. Thank you for your concern

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' (please do not say homework is not relevant) & [ask]. Show what you can do. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & 

ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image 

only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in 

text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 2):

You could join two types of drivers separately and then concat results if that is acceptable:

```
var deliveries = new Delivery[] { };
var internalDrivers = new Driver[] { /*...*/ };
var externalDrivers = new Driver[] { /*...*/ };

var deliveryModels = deliveries.Where(dl => dl.DriverType == "Internal")
    .Join(internalDrivers, delivery => delivery.DriverId, driver => driver.Id,
        (dl, dr) => new DeliveryModel {DeliveryId = dl.Id, DriverName = dr.DriverName})
    .Concat(deliveries.Where(dl => dl.DriverType == "External")
        .Join(externalDrivers, delivery => delivery.DriverId, driver => driver.Id,
            (dl, dr) => new DeliveryModel {DeliveryId = dl.Id, DriverName = dr.DriverName}));

//....
public class  DeliveryModel
{
    public int DeliveryId { get; set; }
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, to avoid Concatenation you could use `GroupJoin` by a combined key of DriverId and DriverType twice to JOIN deliveries to both internal and external drivers and see what matches:

```
var deliveryModels = deliveries.GroupJoin(internalDrivers,
        delivery => (delivery.DriverType, delivery.DriverId), driver => ("Internal", driver.Id),
        (dl, dr) => (dl, dr))
    .GroupJoin(externalDrivers,
        internalDriversJoin => (internalDriversJoin.dl.DriverType, internalDriversJoin.dl.DriverId),
        extDr => ("External", extDr.Id),
        (internalJoinResult, dr) => new DeliveryModel
        {
            DeliveryId = internalJoinResult.dl.Id,
            DriverName = (internalJoinResult.dr.FirstOrDefault() ?? dr?.FirstOrDefault())?.DriverName
        });
```

I have no idea which SQL will be produced in this second query (I hope two LEFT JOINs, but not sure) and what will be the performance of that: it could be better than first query, or it could be worse - just test it before usage in big data scenarios...

If it's for LINQ to objects, I would use first query - it is definitely simpler and should work faster because less objects are created in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
var d = from del in db.deliveries
        join intdrv in db.internalDrivers on new { t = del.DriverType, i = del.DriverId } 
            equals new { t = "Internal", i = intdrv.DriverId } into tdi
        from di in tdi.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join extdrv in db.externalDrivers on new { t = del.DriverType, i = del.DriverId }
            equals new { t = "External", i = extdrv.DriverId } into tde
        from de in tde.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (di ?? de) != null
        select new
        {
            DeliveryId = del.Id,
            DriverName = (di ?? de).DriverName
        };
```

Basically it does two left joins, one for each table, and then uses the null coalescing operator to choose the first non-null result. The where ensures that one of them is found.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not test. But you can try my solution. Hope to help, my friend:

```
var data = from u in Delivery
             select new
             {
                Id = u.Id,
                DriverName = u.DriverType == "Internal" ?  u.InternalDriver.DriverName : u.ExternalDriver.DriverName;                    
              }
```

Comment: what kind of *Lambda query* is this? Shouldn't it contains symbol `=>`?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @Tomato32, Can you update your ans. with a lamda query if possible?

Comment: Your answer relies on the fact that Delivery is already joined somehow both to InternalDriver and to ExternalDriver and does not provide mapping which could make that happen.